# How can I reduce snails in my aquarium without affecting my neocaridinas?

Tags: snails, shrimp

I have an aquarium with some [caridinas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caridina) and [neocaridinas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neocaridina). A few weeks ago, some [snails](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramshorn_snail) showed up (perhaps with new plants) and they're reproducing too fast.

How can I slow down their reproduction or get rid of them?

Comment: I have a similar problem now in one of my shrimp tanks. I added a small jar, placed food inside and take out the snails in the jar daily for a while now.

Comment: I'm sure there's better solutions, but I just plucked them out of my axolotl tank until they stopped showing up.

Comment: related https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-i-reduce-feeding-my-fish-to-keep-my-snail-population-under-control and https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/27067/need-help-with-snails-in-a-betta-tank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Betta Splendens is known to enjoy snacking on (some) snail babies. Other fish are also helpful in this direction.

The downside would be if you also have there baby shrimps. The Betta would happily snack on them too. You just have to identify the type of snail first, and then find their natural predators.